# How to pass a javascript variable to php session

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get the value of a checkbox and assign it to a php session variable. The relevent part of the code is

### The checkbox:

```
$html .= '<span><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox' . $id . '" name="checkbox' . $id . '" onchange="handleCheckboxChange(' . $id . ')"></span>';
```

### The javascript code:

```
echo '<script>

function handleCheckboxChange(id) {
    var checkbox = $("#checkbox" + id);
    var isChecked = checkbox.prop("checked") ? 1 : 0;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_js_php.php",  ///the value of isChecked is sent to the server side and set in a session variable
        data: {
            choosen: isChecked
        },
        success: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "get_session_value.php",  // PHP file to retrieve session set by the update_js_php.php
                success: function () {
                var choose = ' . json_encode("{$_SESSION['choosen']}") . ';
          alert(choose);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

The file update_js_php.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['choosen'] = $_POST['choosen'];
?>
```

The file get_session_value.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo json_encode($_SESSION['choosen']);
?>
```

The problem is that alert(choose) show all the time "1" whatever the value of isChecked.
Any help is appreciated.

I expect a php session variable is set after the checkbox is checked and javascript can read it and show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary fault is here:

```
var choose = ' . json_encode("{$_SESSION['choosen']}") . ';
```

The PHP code show here will execute immediately when your page is first requested, and the *output* of that code will become part of the JavaScript delivered to the page. So if you look in your page's source code (using the browser's Developer Tools) you'll actually see

```
var choose = '1';
```

(assuming the Session value contains `1` as you stated).

What you actually need to do is read the value which was echoed by the `get_session_value.php` script when it's triggered by AJAX - at the moment your code is ignoring this.

So you should actually write:

```
success: function(response) {
  var choose = response;
  alert(choose);
}
```

Note how the `response` value which jQuery passes into the "success" callback contains the data returned by the server in response to the AJAX request. In your case this will contain the echoed Session value, with its latest value.

N.B. Unless your Session value contains a complex variable such as an object or  array, then you don't gain anything by encoding it as JSON. If you're just returning a simple number, then

```
echo json_encode($_SESSION['choosen']);
```

can be simplified to

```
echo $_SESSION['choosen'];
```

with no negative impact.

P.S. You really don't need two separate AJAX requests for this - unless of course you plan in future to send and fetch the Session value at different times and places in your application. I'll assume the way you've structured it in your question is just for demonstration purposes.